# Reduce array of nested object by value of external object

Tags: javascript

I have an array as follow:

```
  const myArray = [
    {
      name: 'banana',
      quotas: [
        {
          title: 'innerBanana1',
          percent: 0.3
        },
        {
          title: 'innerBanana2',
          percent: 0.4
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'apple',
      quotas: [
        {
          title: 'innerApple1',
          percent: 0.6
        },
        {
          title: 'innerApple2',
          percent: 0.2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I would like to sum all the percent in the quotas array only if they belong to the same external object (aka: the name is the same).

**Expected Result**

```
finalArray = [
  { name: 'banana', percent: 0.7 },
  { name: 'apple', percent: 0.8 }
]
```

**I tried**

```
  const sum = quotaGroups
    .map(quotaGroup => quotaGroup.quotas)
    .reduce((accumulator, groupedQuota) => {
      return accumulator + groupedQuota[0].percent
    })
```

But it clearly does not work. I am missing the link on how to sum only the `quotas` of the inner object if the `name` is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to do the reduce inside the map, otherwise the names were getting lost, and the accumulator was trying to concatenate strings, not total up a number.

```js
const myArray = [
  {
    name: 'banana',
    quotas: [{title: 'innerBanana1', percent: 0.3}, {title: 'innerBanana2', percent: 0.4}]
  }, 
  {
    name: 'apple',
    quotas: [{title: 'innerApple1', percent: 0.6}, {title: 'innerApple2', percent: 0.2}]
  }
]

const sum = myArray
  .map(quotaGroup => ({
    name: quotaGroup.name,
    percent: quotaGroup.quotas.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.percent, 0)
  }))

console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` and `reduce`

```js
const sum = (arr) =>
  arr.map(({ quotas, name }) => ({
    name,
    percent: quotas.reduce((sum, { percent }) => sum + percent, 0),
  }));
  
const myArray = [
  {
    name: "banana",
    quotas: [
      {
        title: "innerBanana1",
        percent: 0.3,
      },
      {
        title: "innerBanana2",
        percent: 0.4,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "apple",
    quotas: [
      {
        title: "innerApple1",
        percent: 0.6,
      },
      {
        title: "innerApple2",
        percent: 0.2,
      },
    ],
  },
];



console.log(sum(myArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want:

```js
const myArray = [
    {
        name: 'banana',
        quotas: [
            {
                title: 'innerBanana1',
                percent: 0.3
            },
            {
                title: 'innerBanana2',
                percent: 0.4
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'apple',
        quotas: [
            {
                title: 'innerApple1',
                percent: 0.6
            },
            {
                title: 'innerApple2',
                percent: 0.2
            }
        ]
    }
];

console.log(myArray.map(({ name, quotas }) => {
    return { name, percent: quotas.reduce((a, { percent }) => a + percent, 0) }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use combination of `map` and `reduce` as below

```
const finalArray = myArray.map(item => ({
  name: item.name,
  percent: item.quotas.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur.percent, 0)
}));
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract up-votes.

Answer (score 0):

```
let finalArray  = myArray.map(item => {
    let  percent = 0;
    item.quotas.forEach(function (obj) {
        percent += obj.percent
    });
    return {
        name: item.name,
        percent: percent
    }
})
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.